# How to calculate the difference of hours between two current times based on location

Tags: android, twitter

*I know this may be a simple/duplicate question but somehow I can't manage to calculate it*

Hello, I am fetching today's twitter feeds with their tweeting times and have to calculate the difference of hours between them based on location to show. This is a sample date **`Sun Jul 21 21:14:40 +0000 2013`** and I need to calculate the difference of hours with current time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the first thing to do is to parse that string into a date:

```
Date postDate = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("E MMM d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy")
                                 .parse("Sun Jul 21 21:14:40 +0000 2013");
```

Now, you can get the difference between the post date and the current date in milliseconds:

```
long diffMSec = new Date().getTime() - postDate.getTime();
```

Finally, you can convert the milliseconds to hours, or any other time unit:

```
int diffHours = diffMSec / (1000*60*60);
```

Note that dates only have time zones when represented as strings - internally they're stored as milliseconds since midnight, Jan. 1, 1980, UTC. So parsing the string to a date (using a time zone), and calculating the diff between two dates takes care of the timezone difference for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So this is all the code I need ? I won't need to give any extra effort on calculating time-zone dependent difference?

Comment: Yes - once you convert the string representation to a Date, everything else is done in UTC.